# How can I combine two actions if condition is false in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need a help with one Excel problem. I have a formula that is testing few conditions and when it is True it works as I want it to. Although, I can't figure out how to make a cell be a particular value but also change a content of the next one if condition is False.

I tried using nested Substitute formula but it only works for the cell that you are in so this wasn't successful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

With ms365, you could try the following:

```
=IF(<YourCondition>,<Value>,{<Value1>, <Value2>})
```

This would then spill two values to the right if condition is `FALSE` and just a single one if condition is `TRUE`. For example:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(A1,"a",{"b","c"})
```

This can be further expanded into using actual calculations or any sort of statement using `CHOOSE()`, for example:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(A1,D1,CHOOSE({1,2},D1*3,D1*5)
```

If available the same can be achieved through using `HSTACK()`:

```
=IF(A1,D1,HSTACK(D1*3,D1*5))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work :/

Comment: @Zuzanna, "*This doesn't work*" does not tell me much. Do you not have ms365? In that case you can't spill results with a single formula over a range of cells. It would require multiple formulas in different cells.